# Node.Js: Trying to use bcc instead of To while sending batch email

Tags: node.js, mailgun

I want to send emails in a way where recipients cant see each other email ids. I am using mailgun-api. Here is how my function call currently looks like:

```
mg.sendText(from, [to],
      subject,
      message,
      'yourfriends@abc.com', {},
      function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Email not sent to: ' + to + ', Error:' + err);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Email Sent To' + to);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is send along a `recipient-variables` field in your post.  If you don't need to customize the email body per-user, it should look something like:

```
// map list of recipients to {recipient: {}, ...}
var recipientVariables = to.reduce(
    function(obj, address) { obj[address] = {}; return obj },
    {}
);
```

See [the docs on batch sending](https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#batch-sending) for more details.

However, the [node-mailgun library](https://github.com/shz/node-mailgun) doesn't seem to support setting `recipient-variables`, or have an obvious workaround to cram it in there.  You'd need to stick it into the body they're constructing [here](https://github.com/shz/node-mailgun/blob/master/mailgun.js#L121).  From what I can see, the `sendRaw` method won't let you do it either.

Comment: I did mention i am using mail-gun.

Comment: Googling for "mailgun javascript" gets me this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun-js, which doesn't seem to have a sendText() method in it.  If you actually want help with this, you'll need to provide more information than "I'm using mailgun".

Comment: Oh okay, i am sorry for that. This is the library i am using: 

https://github.com/shz/node-mailgun

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Meteor + Mailgun. I just want to send a batch. I don't want to use the bcc field. Mailgun support isn't very helpful. I was using this tutorial that makes use of the sendRaw method. Trying to insert a recipient-variables field with some JSON just doesn't work, and I haven't found any other options. http://www.curtismlarson.com/blog/2015/07/30/meteor-send-template-emails-from-server-mailgun/